# Same pixel size but different screen size and resolution

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, screen-resolution, screen-size

I've an android project with layouts and resources for screen size large and mdpi (resources are in folders "layout", "drawable", and "drawable-mdpi").
The layout is mostly relative but some margins are given as absolute dp values.

The screens look perfectly on a device with above specifications (large/mdpi: aka device 1) and a pixel resolution of 480x800. Now, I have another device which has the same pixel resolution of 480x800 but since the screen is smaller, it has screen size normal and hdpi (aka device 2). The screens on device 2 look really messy (elements overlap etc.)

Since the pixel resolution is identical on both devices, it should be possible to create perfectly fitting screens for device 2 as well with little effort.
If I don't care about elements physically appearing smaller on device 2, what would be the approach to just physically "scale" my layouts (to fit on device 2)?

Just copying the drawable-mdpi to drawable-hdpi helps a little bit, but there are still problems. Are the absolute dp margins in the layout the problem? Should they be replaced by pixel dependent ones and everything is OK?

In general, what are best practices when I want to use a design that was originally created for a specific pixel resolution on devices with different pixel resolutions and I don't care much about elements appearing smaller or bigger?

In my case I basically just want to "scale" the original design and I don't care much about the vertical size (because the main view is scrollable anyway).

Comment: The best practice is to never create for a specific pixel resolution.